# phpMyAdmin SQL - Temporary Tables

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I need some assistance with creating temporary tables in phpMyAdmin sql from data in a current table. For example, I have a table called `Animals` with several columns, one of these columns is called `Animal_Size`, and I am required to create a temporary table called `Small Animals` consisting of the animals in the `Animals` table where the `size` is **small**. 
Can someone guide me as to the best way to go about doing this?

I've seen some examples but a lot of them don't seem to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to select all small animals into new table, you want to use this query:

```
CREATE TABLE small_animals SELECT * FROM animals WHERE animal_size = 'small'
```

If you need real temporary table, then just add TEMPORARY into the query:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE small_animals_temp SELECT * FROM animals WHERE animal_size = 'small'
```

Update: Because of problem within the parser in phpMyAdmin, add `AS` before the `SELECT`, i.e.:

```
CREATE TABLE small_animals AS SELECT * FROM animals WHERE animal_size = 'small'
```

> Note: A TEMPORARY table is visible only to the current connection, and
>   is dropped automatically when the connection is closed.

Comment: Hey, Thanks for the response.

I get an error under SELECT though saying "An opening bracket was expected. (Near select).

Comment: This is known issue in phpMyAdmin, see here: https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/issues/12109. Try to update it to latest version, to add `AS` before the `SELECT` or run the SQL query via console or other mysql client.